# How to convert row value to column

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have this table below. Let's just call it phone

```
--------------------------
| userid | type | number |
--------------------------
| 1      | home | 123456 |
--------------------------
| 1      |office| 654321 |
--------------------------
```

so I want it to be like this:

```
--------------------------
| userid | home | office |
--------------------------
| 1      |123456| 654321 |
--------------------------
```

I'm trying pivot table but the problem is that I don't have any field to aggregate. Any suggestion?

PS
I'm using Azure SQL Server

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Azure SQL Server sorry forgot to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
with your_table( userid , type , number) as (
    select 1      ,'home','123456' union all
    select 1      ,'office','654321' union all
    select 2      ,'home','4444' union all
    select 3      ,'office','77777'  
)

-- below is actual query:

select coalesce(t1.userid, t2.userid) as userid, t1.home, t2.office from
(select userid, number as home from your_table where type = 'home') t1
full join 
(select userid, number as office from your_table where type = 'office' ) t2
on t1.userid = t2.userid
```

If you have another values also in `type` column, and you need display they as columns, then you should add another subquery and `full join` also.

Comment: wow dude. i just tried your query. seriously this saves me thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

in case you don't have duplicate values:

```
select 
    user_id,
    min(case when type='home' then type else null end) home,
    min(case when type='office' then type else null end) office
from
    phone
group by
    userid;
```